# QQ plot for a fitted normal / lognormal distrbution

Tags: r, statistics, risk-analysis

I'm having problems generating a QQ plot for a fitted distrubution.
The data is fitted by

```
NormalFit <- fitdistr(obs, densfun="normal")
```

where obs are the observations.

I thought I can just do

```
qqnorm(NormalFit)
```

I want to do the same for

```
LogNormalFit <- fitdistr(obs, densfun="log-normal")
```

Answer (score 1):

the fit only gives you the inferred parameters, so you need to sample from that, to give you the qqplot. See below for 3 examples on how to do it.

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(999)
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
#simulate data
obs = rnegbin(500, mu = 5, theta = 4)
#fit data 
NormalFit <- fitdistr(obs, densfun="normal") 

#plot
qqnorm(obs,main="qqnorm")
# generate theoretical quantiles
Theo_Quantile = qnorm(ppoints(length(obs)))
qqplot(Theo_Quantile,obs,main="ppoint")
# it's also similar to if you just sample from the fitted distribution
Fitted = rnorm(length(obs),NormalFit$estimate[1],NormalFit$estimate[2])
qqplot(Fitted,obs,main="Sampled from fitted")
```

[image]